# thrift api java client connect with HBase

Tags: java, dependencies, hbase, thrift

**Packages uses:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.AlreadyExists;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.ColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.IOError;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.IllegalArgument;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Mutation;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.TCell;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.TRowResult;

import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;
```

**Call Method**

```
public void start() {
            try {
                TTransport socket = new TSocket("host-name", 9090);// IP Host Name
                TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(socket, true, true);// Note here
                Hbase.Client client = new Hbase.Client(protocol);
                socket.open();
                System.out.println("open");
                try {
                    System.out.println("scanning tables...");
                    for (byte[] name : client.getTableNames()) { 
                        //code
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                socket.close();
                out.println("close");
            } catch (TTransportException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
}
```

**Problem:**

code java
get error: invalid method name: 'getTableNames' 
i can't give list tables in Hbase
maybe I have a problem on a missed package

### thanks for helping

Comment: You are using the wrong API on either client or server side. HBase has an old and a new Thrift API. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874861/hbase-thrift-in-cdh-5), same problem. -1 for not doing your homework before asking: [The very same question has been asked just yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371444/tapplicationexception-invalid-method-name-gettablenames-for-hbase-thrift-nodej).

Comment: thanks Jens for your reply,I tried to look for the new Thrift API, but still no results, thank you for helping.

Comment: The error message `invalid method name` is raised whenever a client calls a method that the server does not know. The only possible reasons are (1) server and client are speaking different API versions, this is the most common error with HBase, or (2) the client talks to a completely wrong server which happens to implement another Thrift-based API. The latter is very unlikely, but still possible. And that's it. If you have "*still no results*" you should be more specific, why the solution did not help you.

Comment: I'll try to see these two possibilities, you will be aware, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

thanks, problem is solved, i used DemoClient.java in **hbase-0.94.19.tar.gz\hbase-0.94.19\src\examples\thrift2**, this rar than i have installed on server. and I added this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-thrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.2-hadoop2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```